# Flutter & Github Actions: Create unsigned APK (Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease')

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk, github-actions

I am using **GitHub actions** to build my Flutter APK for testing purposes.
Recently I built and signed my app and released it to Google Play, however, by doing this I broke my GitHub Action.

I get this error now when my action runs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

This is the action:

```
name: APK

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: '11'
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter test
      - run: flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons
      - run: flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons
      - run: sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: apk
          path: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

So I guess there are two ways to solve this and I'd like to have an answer to both:

1. How can I continue to build unsigned APKs with GitHub Actions?
2. How can I build an actual signed APK ready for release with GitHub Actions?

Keep in mind that building locally works fine (because all required files are present locally to build a signed APK).

---

**Edit #01:**

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```dart
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "at.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}
...
```

Comment: In build settings you would have configured the release set up. Please revert it and you should be able to build an apk. Place where you define build types

Comment: I have added my build.gradle file. I do not want to remove it. I want to be able to build a signed apk and a unsigned apk with my github aciton :/

Comment: https://medium.com/@seshasai_30381/flutter-github-actions-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-flutter-apps-with-github-actions-fastlane-and-7e34d9727b2a

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How can I continue to build unsigned APKs with GitHub Actions?

If you want to build an ***unsigned*** release APK, then you will need to remove the entire `release` section of your `signingConfigs` in the `build.gradle` and then when your `assembleRelease` task runs, it won't attempt to sign the APK anymore.

> 2. How can I build an actual signed APK ready for release with GitHub Actions?

You would need to add the signing certificates to your CI, in GitHub Actions, you should be able to use the [encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) with your signing certificates to achieve this. If you do this, you can avoid doing the first option entirely.

Alternatively, you can look into creating a new signing profile specifically for the GitHub Actions CI using variants and have a different one for local development. I would recommend reading up about it on the [Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Answer (score -1):

..
android {
compileSdkVersion 31

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "at.test.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

}
..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).